# Regex to get information of comma seperated column list by alias

Tags: c#, regex

The original Question is to determine what the original column were from in a comma seperated list of columns which can be aliases. This list is out of any Select Block in SQL because the Syntax is nearly the same. I am using MSSQL. And my Regex should work with C# Code! So I started matching what's between columns. Then I specified that the end of the content should be something like "column" enclosed by brackets (or ' when there is more content than multiply spaces). And this end have to be exactly. So , bla as blacolumn, is not a valid match of what I am trying to get (get means in this case read the match value for more edit).
The match of the value should only be the value itself when there is no additional Information for it:

```
SELECT
  text
FROM
  bla
```

else only the information should be matched without the "text":

```
SELECT
  bla.t as text
FROM
  bla
```

or

```
SELECT
  t as text
FROM
  bla
```

So I got a little example where I highlighted what should be matched:

SELECT **text** FROM

SELECT **bla.t as** text FROM

SELECT **t as** text FROM

SELECT bla.tatext FROM

SELECT **bla.** text FROM

SELECT bla.t as tatext FROM

SELECT **bla.t as** text FROM

SELECT bla.t as tatext, **bla.t as** text FROM

,**text** FROM ( SELECT **bla.** text FROM ) as bla

,'text' FROM

,**[text]** FROM

,**bla.t as** 'text',

Just copy this example and try to get all the higlighted . as matches

Good Luck!

Comment: What regex language are you using? What do you mean by "get"? Is that what you want to capture?

Comment: Oh and I am Using C# ... Sorry for that I forgot to add this :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question. It sounds like all you need is

```
,([^,]*?text),
```

That will match a comma, 0 or more non-comma characters ending with `text` and another comma. Since only the text between the commas is in parentheses, that is all that would be captured.

If you don't want to include `text` in the match, you could do

```
,([^,]*?)text,
```

Or, if you don't want to use capturing and insist on lookarounds:

```
(?<=,)(.*?)(?=text,)
```

The details will depend on the regex language you are using.

Comment: The Problem is that this

, text,**ttast, teast, taeastxt,bb_t.dasasd as** text,bb_t.asdasd AS  tatext ,

is a match :D And I dont want that :D

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern

```
(?<=\,)(.*?)(?<=text)(?=\,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert either but does this work for what you want?

text(?=,)

That uses a positive lookahead (?=,) following the key word you want.

If you only want the keyword when it's between comma's, you could us a lookhead and look behind:

(?<=,\s*)text(?=,)

Comment: I am sorry but this does not fit my intention